# Show that the space $\{a,b\}^{\Bbb N}$ is zero dimensional when each $\{a,b\}$ has the discrete topology.

Tags: general-topology

> Show that the space $\{a,b\}^{\Bbb N}$ is zero dimensional when each $\{a,b\}$ has the discrete topology.

I've seen that we cannot just conclude that $\{a,b\}^{\Bbb N}$ is discrete because the "factors" are discrete. We need to show that $\{a,b\}^{\Bbb N}$ has a base consisting of singletons.

By the product topology the base of $\{a,b\}^{\Bbb N}$ consists of $\prod_{i \in I} U_i$ where $U_i$ is open in $\{a,b\}$ and $U_i=\{a,b\}$ for all but finitely many $i \in I$.

So let $I'$ be the set of indices for which $U_i \ne \{a,b\}$. For any $i \in I'$ we now have that $U_i=\{a\}, \{b\}$ or $\emptyset$. So some element $B$ of the basis could be for example $$\{a\} \times \{b\} \times \{a,b\} \times \{a,b\} \times \dots$$

This is by definition open so in order for the topology to be discrete if I can show that the complement is also open I've shown that the base consists of clopen sets making the topology discrete.

I don't know how to compute the complement of $$\{a\} \times \{b\} \times \{a,b\} \times \{a,b\} \times \dots?$$

Comment: The complement of $\{a\} \times \{b\} \times \{a,b\} \times \{a,b\} \times \dots$ is $\{b\} \times \{a\} \times \emptyset \times \emptyset \times \dots$.

Comment: What is your definition of "zero dimensional"? By the way, your space is not discrete and thus cannot have base consisting of singletons.

Comment: @Davide No it's not.

Comment: @PaulFrost having a base of clopen sets is the standard definition, as you probably know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complement of $\{a\} \times \{b\} \times \{a,b\} \times \{a,b\} \times \ldots$ is  $(\{b\} \times \{a,b\} \times \{a,b\} \times \{a,b\} \times \ldots) \cup (\{a,b\} \times \{a\} \times \{a,b\} \times \{a,b\} \times \ldots)$.

Because either the first coordinate isn't $a$ or the second isn't $b$, to be in the complement. No condition on the other coordinates.

So the complement of an open set is open again so clopen. We only need a base of clopen sets to show zero-dimensionality.

In fact generalise to "the product of any family of zero-dimensional spaces is zero-dimensional". And discrete spaces are zero-dimensional.